# What is the part of speech and meaning of ‘likely’ in the following passage?

Tags: meaning, difference

> It is important to know how to identify what a reference word refers to. Some questions in the exam are **likely** to test this ability.

If the meaning of ‘likely’ in this passage is ‘possible’, then what the difference between them?

Thanks!

Comment: "Likely" is an adjective here functioning as a predicative complement with the infinitival clause "to test this ability" as its complement. It expresses medium epistemic modality, and hence is sometimes called a lexical modal. "Possibly" is also a lexical modal, but it can't here replace "likely". Note, though, that you could say "Some questions in the exam may possibly test this ability".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't replace the adjective 'likely' with 'possible' in your sentence:

'It is important to know how to identify what a reference word refers to. Some questions in the exam are *likely* to test this ability'.

You would have to say '...some questions in the exam *may* test this ability.' This is because 'possible' is not a verb.

That said,

'Likely' has a greater chance of occurring than 'possible' (or 'may').

In fact 'likely' means it has about 50% chance of happening, whereas 'possible' or 'may' gives no indication of probability at all.

Examples:

- it is likely to rain tomorrow (50% probability)
- it is possible it will rain tomorrow (rain sometimes happens...)
- It may rain tomorrow (or, it may not!)

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_of_estimative_probability

Comment: But "likely" is an adjective here, not an adverb!

Comment: Thanks @BillJ Yes I just read that, somewhere else!